# How to migrate Ubuntu12.04 to LVM without any data loss

Tags: 12.04, lvm

The current system is installed on the traditional disk, now I want to migrate it to LVM managed disk, how can I migrate it without any data loss?
I'm working with vSphere, so I can add and remove disk easily, change system to another virtual disk and rebooting are acceptable.
Is there someone can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge it has no real easy way. I've done this operation by making a backup / restore from a partition to another.

Have you watched the btrfs file system that provides some similar functionality to LVM ? I recently installed a machine with this file system and I'm very happy. In addition, there are commands to convert ext4 to btrfs.

Comment: Perhaps this link can help you [Fastest way to convert an ext4 formatted disk to LVM with ext4 on it?](http://superuser.com/questions/493481/fastest-way-to-convert-an-ext4-formatted-disk-to-lvm-with-ext4-on-it)

Comment: I think I can copy / to the LVM managed partion, and then modify grub and MBR. But I don't know how to modify them, and should the kernal be updated?

Comment: I think there is no need to update or change your kernel. However, I've always done this sort of operation for "system partitions" with fresh install.

Another way will be to keep / and /boot in ext4 without LVM then create new partitions for /home, /opt, etc. and move only your datas in LVM partitions.